# image size advice

Tags: android, image, size

In researching android image sizes for different sized screens/densities etc., I've found an absolute tonne of things, a lot of which may be deprecated, and a lot of which may not be relevant to my situation, so I thought I'd ask for general advice.

My basic question is how big should I make my background image in pixels, or inches or centimetres? Probably pixels would be best.

My app is in locked in landscape mode, I don't need to worry about orientation.

I'm using a vector image, so I don't need to worry about scaling and quality issues

So, I want my background image to fit onto a ten inch tablet, so that it fills the whole screen with no scrolling.

On phones, I want the height(which would be the width in portrait mode) to match the height of the screen, and my image will be in a horizontal scroll view, so scrolls left and right in landscape mode.

So, do I need to do the whole creating different image resources for different dpi's thing, or will one do? What size should I make it?

I will also be lining up textviews with specific parts of the image, so presumably I'll need different layouts, as the lining up of textviews relative to the image will probably vary from screen size to screen size, resolution to resolution,bigger textviews for bigger screens etc. How do I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a big vector graphic then the system might hang at it takes time to calculate everything and it will make everything slow. If you are uning a full screen image then you should go for .png files as they are very easy to load without any calculations.

Comment: Ok, what size should I make the images for different densities? This is what I'm stuck on really. Sarthak, it is a .png.

Comment: If it is a big image then yes you have to make it for different densities png files. If you are using a small the you have to make a single svg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector images should be used for icons only. In your case i'd just use a drawable & make sure you have different images for the different densities. Then create different layouts for phone and tablet. You should use a scrollview on the layout for the phone

The google pixel is a good representation of an android phone: It has a 1080 x 1920 resolution at 441 dpi. Then from the the android developer docs:

> xxhdpi ~ 480dpi

you can scale the 1080 x 1920 down by the (3:4:6:8:12) ratios. if you image
has a different aspect ratio make sure that that the width or the height matches with 1080 x 1920 depending on the orientation of the device

Comment: OK, so if we take my Samsung S8, the resolution is set to 2960x1440, 570 ppi (I'm assuming ppi is the same as dpi?) . So, what size should an image be to fit the screen perfectly, with the imageview's height and width set to wrap_content? What is the formula? Sorry I really need to get this clear in my head (which hurts)

Comment: this isn't the point of my post. The Pixel is the most standard android device and I use that fact to point out that you should use 1080x1920 for xxhdpi and scale that down to each density.

Comment: for tablet use the "android:background" attribute on your root layout. For phones use a scrollview that contains an ImageView with wrap_content for the width and match_parent for the height because you want the height of the image to be equal to the height in landscape mode